# Showing set is closed and other sets not closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

For $i=1$ and $i=2$, consider the mappings $q_i$:  $\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $q_i$($x_1$,$x_2$)=$x_i$ ( that is, $q_1$ and $q_2$ are projections on the x and y axis respectively).  Please show that the set G:={($x_1$,$x_2$) $\in$ $\mathbb{R^2}$, $x_1$$x_2$=1} is closed in $\mathbb{R^2}$ but neither $q_1$(G) nor $q_2$(G) are closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Thoughts/Attempt to think about it: I know how to show a set is generally closed(have done so many times) either proving that the set contains its limit points or that the complement of the set is open.  How do I show that the complement of the set G is open?  I don't really have much intuition for this problem as I haven't encountered or seen a problem like it in any text (this is my first introduction to analysis/topology).  Generally, to show a set is open I show that all the points are interior points.  That is, for each point in the set G complement, I show that there exists a ball around it that is fully contained in the set.  However, I don't know how to formalize this argument to this particular question or if this is even the right approach (should I consider limit points instead?)

Also I know that if  neither $q_1$(G) nor $q_2$(G) are closed in $\mathbb{R}$, that does not mean that they are open, they could be clopen.   If I show that they are indeed open, then neither are closed.  However I do not think that this is necessarily the best strategy as I don't know beforehand whether they are clopen or open.

Any help, guidance, instruction, pointers would be much welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I pressume that you use te Euclideian metric $d_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $d_2(x,y)=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}$

Let $x_n=(x_n^1,x_n^2) \in G$ such that $x_n \to^{d_2} x=(x_1,x_2)$

Then it is not difficult to see that $$x_n^1 \to x_1$$ $$x_n^2 \to x_2$$

Thus $1=x_n^1x_n^2 \to x_1x_2$,so from uniqueness of limit we have that $x_1x_2=1$ so $x=(x_1,x_2) \in G.$

Thus from the sequentail  characterization of closedness we prove that $G$ is closed.

Now if $(x_1,x_2) \in G$ we have that $x_1,x_2 \neq 0$ and $x_1=\frac{1}{x_2}$

So $q_1(G)=\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ which is an open set as a complement of a singleton which is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Apply the same argument for $q_2(G)$

Comment: For our class, we have not discussed the sequentail characterization of closedness .  Is there a way to prove it showing the complement is open.  Also shouldn't q1(G)=R\ {0} not R^2.  Thanks.

Comment: @BOB there is a way but believe me sequential characterization of closedness is much more quicker and easier to use and its valid for all metric spaces...

Comment: Thanks except it is a concept that I have not learned.  Is there a way you could help me formalize an argument using the approach I mentioned?Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$q_1(G) = q_2(G) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} $$

Comment: This may be an obvious thing: but how do we know 0 is not contained?

Comment: Is it because x1x2=1

Comment: What is $G$? pairs of number ($x_1$) and its inverse. $0$ has no inverse. So, no $(0, x)$ in $G$, nor $(x, 0)$, for any $x$.

Comment: Great that makes sense.

Comment: So knowing that q1(G)=R\{0} implies q1(G) is not closed because it doesn't contain all its limit points? Sorry if some of these questions may be obvious, am a beginner.

Comment: But, it's an open set.

Comment: Should I formally show that it is an open set? What is the motivation behind it being an open set?  I know that generally R is both open and closed if we take it to be the largest space.  What is the intuition behind  R\0 being open?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Marios supplied a cool argument. $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ is open as a compliment of $\{0\}$, which is closed

Comment: @BOB Both sets equal $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and this set is open, but formally from that you cannot conclude yet that it is not closed (and that was to be proved). You are on the right track by observing that the set does not contain all its limit points. If you use that argument then you must prove that $0$ is indeed a limit point of $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and you are ready. Another way is looking at the complement of $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ which is the singleton $\{0\}$. Proving that this set is not open is the same as proving that $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

(I). A set can be open or closed or both or neither. The definition of a closed set is the complement of an open set.

(II).In $\Bbb R$ the definition of the usual (standard) topology is that  $S$ is open iff for each $x\in S$ there is an $r_x>0$ such that $(-r_x+x,r_x+x)\subset S.$ In particular $\emptyset$ is open (as there is no $x$ in $\emptyset$ that violates the condition for being open) and $\emptyset$ is closed because its complement $\Bbb R$ is open.

In $\Bbb R$ there are other, equivalent ways to define closed sets.

(III). The projection  of $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb r^2:xy=1\}$ onto either its $1$st or $2$nd co-ordinate is $T= \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}.$ Now $T$ is open because if $0\ne x\in \Bbb R$ then $|x|/2>0$ and $0\ne (-|x|/2+x, |x|/2+x)$ so $(-|x|/2+x,|x|/2+x)\subset T.$ And also $\Bbb R \setminus T=\{0\}$ is closed.

(IV). In $\Bbb R^2$ there are several (equivalent ) ways to define the usual (standard) topology. For example:

(a).For $p=(x,y)$ and $p'= (x',y')$ in $\Bbb R^2$ define $d(p,p')=\sqrt {(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2}\;.$

For $0<r\in \Bbb R$ and $p\in \Bbb R^2$ the set $B_d(p,r)=\{p'\in \Bbb R^2: d(p,p')<r\}$ is a circular region with center $p$ and radius $r.$

Define $S\subset \Bbb R^2$ to be $d$-open iff for each $p\in S$ there is an $r_p>0$ such that $B_d(p,r_p)\subset S.$

(b). For $p=(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$ and $p'=(x',y')$ let $e(p,p')=\max (|x-x'|,|y-y'|).$ For $0<r\in \Bbb R$ and $p\in  \Bbb R^2$ the set $B_e(p,r)=\{p'\in \Bbb R^2: e(p,p')<r\}$ is a square region with sides parallel to the co-ordinate axes, with center $p,$ and with side-length $2r.$

Define $S\subset \Bbb R^2$ to be $e$-open iff for each $p\in S$ there is an $s_p>0$ such that $B_e(p,s_p)\subset S.$

(c). $d$-open and $e$-open are equivalent:

(c-1). If $S\subset \Bbb R^2$ is $d$-open is open and $p\in S$  take $r_p>0$ such that $B_d(p,r_p)\subset S.$ Let $s_p=r_p/2.$ Then $s_p>0$ and $B_e(p,s_p)\subset B_d(p,r_p)\subset S.$ Therefore if $S$ is $d$-open then $S$ is $e$-open.

(c-2). If $S\subset \Bbb R^2$ is $e$-open  and $p\in S$  take $s_p>0$ such that $B_e(p,s_p)\subset S.$ Let $r_p=s_p.$ Then $r_p>0$ and $B_d(p,r_p)\subset B_e(p,s_p)\subset S.$ Therefore if $S$ is $e$-open then $S$ is $d$-open.

Being $d$-open (equivalently $e$-open) means being open in the usual (standard) topology on $\Bbb R^2.$

(V). Let $H=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2: xy\ne 1\}.$ For $p=(x,y)\in H$ let $xy=1+z.$

We have $z\ne 0$. Take  $s_p>0$ such that $s_p^2<|z|/3$ and $s_p|y|<|z|/3$ and $s_p|x|<|z|/3.$

For $(x',y')\in B_e(p,s_p)$ let $x'=x+u$ and $y'=y+v.$ We have $|u|<s_p$ and $|v|<s_p.\;$ And  $$x'y'-1=(x+u)(y+v)-1=(xy-1)+(uy+vx+uv)=z+(uy+vx+uv).$$ Now $$|uy+vx+uv|\leq |u|\cdot |y|+|v|\cdot |x|+|u|\cdot |v|\leq$$ $$\leq  s_p|y|+s_p|x|+s_p^2<|z|/3+|z|/3+|z|/3=|z|.$$ So $z\ne -(uy+vx+uv),$ implying $x'y'\ne 1,$ implying  $(x',y')\in H.$ Therefore $B_e(p,s_p)\subset H.$ So $H$ is open.

Comment: Try the following topics in Wkipedia: Topology. Topological Space.